# ng-repeat is not working in get method in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

Actually, I wrote code in angularjs, In web browser displays the retrieve data but it ng-repeat is not working. I dont know how to fix it. could you help me?

In angular js code

```
$scope.fetchData = function()
{
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'fetch_data.php'
    }).then(function (response){
        console.log(response);
        namesData = response.data;
        console.log(namesData );
    },function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in namesData ">
   <td>{{name.first_name}}</td>
   <td>{{name.last_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Browser displays

```
{mydata: Array(0), namesData: "<[{"first_name":"xvcv","last_name":"sdsd"},{"first_name":"sdvs","last_name":"sdfds"}]"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `namesData` with `$scope.namesData`.

You can't bind ordinary variables to your template/view. You need to use `$scope/$rootScope` for that.

```
$scope.namesData = []; //you need to instantiate this first to avoid errors

$scope.fetchData = function()
{
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'fetch_data.php'
  }).then(function (response){
    console.log(response);
    $scope.namesData = response.data;
    console.log($scope.namesData );
  },function (error){
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

P.S.

**Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]**

> Occurs if there are duplicate keys in an ngRepeat expression.
>   Duplicate keys are banned because AngularJS uses keys to associate DOM
>   nodes with items.

This means that `$scope.namesData` have some values which are duplicate.
You can solve by adding `"track by $index"`.

It will look like this

`ng-repeat="name in namesData track by $index"`

Comment: ReferenceError: namesData is not defined error came dude

Comment: try adding `$scope.namesData = [];` above and outside that fetchdata function.

Comment: dude again namesData is not defined error and  Error: [ngRepeat: dupes] came

Comment: That's weird. I know where the dupes error comes from but the namesData not defined is really weird. Can you post your whole controller code for me to have a wider look? If it wont compromise.

Comment: Your controller seems fine even though I can't find where did you initially call your fetch. Did you put `ng-controller="crudController"` in your template/html? And does `console.log($scope.namesData );` logs something?

Comment: var app = angular.module('crudApp', ['datatables']);
app.controller('crudController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
 
 $scope.namesData = [];

 $scope.refresh = function(){
     fetchData();
    };
 
 $scope.fetchData = function()
 {
  
   $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'fetch_data.php'
    }).then(function (response){
     console.log(response);
     $scope.namesData = response.data;
     console.log(namesData);
     },function (error){
      console.log(error);
     });
 };
}]);